# Eclipse Google App Engine Server cannot be reached via the actual IP

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, ip

Tool: Eclipse Luna
Language: Java
Component: Android, Google Appengine (Endpoint) and Enterprise Application Project.

At first, I created an Android application and used it to generate the Cloud Endpoint Backend.

I was able to connect to the dev server via the IP of my laptop.

Then, I realized that my approach is no longer valid, because I need to create some module to run some background process.

After doing some research, I ended up creating an Enterprise Application Project and link the cloud endpoint project under it and host them w/ Google App Engine server.

Well, the server runs just fine and I can still use the developer console to test the API and see the datastore, I can even get to the home page via 127.0.0.1, but I just couldn't get to the server via the actual IP.  That's the IP that I need to use to connect from my device which is plugged in via USB.

I tried to use the "--address" parameter under the Run/Configuration, but Eclipse keeps on overwrite back to the default value.  Can anyone help?  pppppplease!

Comment: are client and server on the same PC/network?

Comment: @jirungaray...yes, the server runs on my laptop and the device is plugged in thru USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that Server configuration override the **Run/Run Configurations!**

The **Servers** screen should already be opened on the bottom of your Eclipse editor.  If not, you can open it via **Window/Show Views/Servers**.

Double click on the server that you are interested and you will see the **Overview** screen on above the Servers screen.

In the **Overview**, look for the section **Application Server** and there should be a field called "**Local interface address to bind to**."  Well, set that to **0.0.0.0**, so it will bind to all IPs.

Don't forget to restart your server!  :)  Happy coding....